# To remove Order number from the Email in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

When a Order is placed in Netsuite , Order confirmation email is sent . I am  using Basic Html Layout I have the below Subject Line in the email , I would like to remove the Ordernumber: #0000706  from the subject line .

AAA Inc ,Order information #0000706

Comment: Are you saying about the "Email" option under "Actions" menu in the sales order record ??

Comment: Thank you Frederick. In Sales Order > Communication tab > TO BE E-MAILED check box checked.

Comment: @madura-Bhat .. That is a standard functionality in NetSuite that have the default subject linbe in this format. The subject line cannot be customized / configured in this case.

Comment: Thank you Frederick , I appreciate all the help